# MySQL/PHP: Looking for matching records from three tables(Forum permissions)

Tags: php, mysql, html, permissions, forum

Maybe I am not putting the search in correctly in Google or SOF.com, but perhaps someone is willing to assist regardless. I know this is not the best method, but I am learning and I am hoping someone can assist in this way. I have a forum system in PHP/MySQL. The forum is set up to have an ID column.

I now also have 2 tables. One is a group table and the other is a forum permission table. The group table has an ID column and a user_id column, both int. The Forum Permission table has an id, forum_id and group_id. Basically I am trying find if the user belongs to a group(Group Table) and if that group is allowed to be in that forum(Forum Permission Table). The problem is that the user can belong to multiple groups and each forum can have multiple groups assigned to it.

Is there a query which can basically just search the three tables and distinguish if the user has access to the forum? If it were just one group to one forum, or one group per user, I can figure that out, but in this case I am stuck.

Any help? Example of Table structure below:

This is the Forum Table

```
Forum_ID || Forum_Name  
 1       ||| General tal
```

k

For Group Table:

```
Group_id ||| Group_name     ||| User_ID  
1        ||| Administrators ||| 2
```

For the Forum permission table(Forum_ID corresponds to Forum_ID in the Forums Table and Group_To_Allow corresponds to Group_ID on the groups table):

```
ID ||| Forum_ID ||| Group_To_Allow  
1  ||| 1        ||| 1
```

Best I can do with the formatting.

EDIT:

OK, I figured it out with the InnerJoin. So using the table structure above:

```
SELECT *
FROM forum_perm
INNER JOIN membergroups
ON forum_perm.forum_groupallow=membergroups.group_id
WHERE forum_perm.forum_id = 1 AND membergroups.user_id = 6
LIMIT 0,1
```

Forum_perm.forum_id = 1 is the id number of the forum to check for the group. Membergroups.user_id = 6 is the users id number that belongs to the that group. The limit 0,1 will limit the result to just return one result instead of looping over and over. This is good because in PHP if MySQL loops through all the results and finds one group that does not match, it will still return false. Hope this helps anyone who is trying to achieve something similar.

Comment: Rather than describing your tables, can you post their actual structure, via `SHOW CREATE TABLE forum; SHOW CREATE TABLE group; SHOW CREATE TABLE permission`, and post a small sample of rows for each.

Comment: (two inner joins across 3 tables will be the solution, ultimately)

Comment: OK, so if I do an inner join(Which I would actually only need to do across two tables(Forum Permissions and Group tables) and it will return the search I need. However, I do not need it to keep looping through and finding every single result. I need the query to stop as soon as it finds a result and then have PHP Return a true statement if it finds a matching result and false if it loops through and finds no match. Anyway to stop it once it finds the search?

Comment: To format code blocks, highlight them and `ctl-k` or click the `{}` editor toolbar button - these will indent them 4 spaces as a code block.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the idea on the InnerJoin. Look above. I was able to solve the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: When the timeout expires and you are permitted to, you  should post your solution as an answer below, then mark it as accepted after 2 days (I think?) have passed.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a JOIN statement and only select the highest value with MAX() from the certain row you want. I don't know your exact table structure or how you're doing that with the forum permissions. If you have only one column in your user table (I guess that's what you have, since that's usually the case), you maybe can use it in a IN statement (WHERE field IN(...). Maybe it works to just say mysql, hey take the value of this field (if the value of this field is commata-separated). I've never done it so I don't know it works.

Maybe you should make us some screenshots from your tables in phpmyadmin, so we can give you more accurate and specific informations.

edit: It does work with just throwing the name of the column.

Comment: So to explain the table(I can not seem to press enter in reply):<br> Forum_ID || Forum_Name<br> 1  |||  General talk. <br><br> For Group Table:  <br><br>Group_id  ||| Group_name  ||| User_ID <br> 1  ||| Administrators |||  2 <br><br><br> For the Forum permission table: <br> ID  ||| Forum_ID  ||| Group_To_Allow  <br> 1 |||  1 ||| 1 <br>Hope this explains it better.  Still cant seem to format it correctly on my reply.

Comment: @user1924218 Don't post this in comments. Please edit your question above to include the table structures.